# How can I get started learning Sitecore?

Tags: community

I'm about to start on a Sitecore project in 6-8 weeks time. I have extensive ASP.NET MVC experience (4 years) and know the ins-and-outs of web development fairly well.

I am scheduled for official Sitecore developer training in 4 weeks. I would like to prepare myself further by learning as much as I can from online, freely available resources.

I am aware of the [extensive blogging community that exists](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/), but most of these blogs are focused at developers with some level of expertise. At this point I am more after resources that focus on learning and training from ground up.

Where can I go to find information like this?  Any community resources?  E-books?  Webinars?  Youtube tutorials?

Also; if anyone can recommend any books I can buy, that would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 56):

*Answering as a community edit; hoping everyone will get engaged in compiling this list.*

---

## Trials

Do you want to know more about how to build with Sitecore products? Learn more about the trials Sitecore offers for some of the products in our composable DXP.

https://developers.sitecore.com/trials

---

## Online Sitecore Learning Resources

### Online Training/E-Learning

- **Official Sitecore learning website**
- [Learning@Sitecore (learning.sitecore.com)](https://learning.sitecore.com/)
- **Official Sitecore developer documentation**
- [Developers documentation (doc.sitecore.com)](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers)
- [Helix documentation (helix.sitecore.net)](https://helix.sitecore.net/)
- [JSS Getting Started (jss.sitecore.com)](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs)
- [Knowledge Base (kb.sitecore.net)](https://kb.sitecore.net)
- [Knowledge Center - Getting Started (sitecore.com)](https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started)
- [Boxever training is free for everyone](https://learning.sitecore.com/pathway/boxever-training)
- [Ordercloud (Four51) you can create a free account and start learning](https://www.ordercloud.io/learn/ordercloud-basics/architecture)

---

- **The Unofficial Sitecore 8 Training Webinar Series**
- http://www.akshaysura.com/2016/02/03/unofficial-sitecore-8-training-webinar-series-full-curriculum/
- Coordinator: [@akshaysura13](https://twitter.com/akshaysura13)

---

- **Sitecore Community Docs**
- Documentation and guides written by the community for developers. This is an open source initiative that the community can edit and contribute back to.
- Url: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/

---

- **The Sitecore Link Project**
- This is the most complete collection of Sitecore references ever to exist, verified and classified for your convenience. It also has a section for the beginners for easier start.
- Url: http://sitecore.link/
- You may also subscribe to 300+ RSS feeds of all Sitecore bloggers: http://sitecore.link/rss so that you'll get updated with dozens of new posts daily.

---

- **Learn Sitecore CMS - Jon D Jones**
- Tutorials, developers guide, content editors guide, and free video tutorials.
- Url: https://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/

---

### YouTube

- **Sitecore's Official Education Channel - Discover Sitecore**
- https://www.youtube.com/c/DiscoverSitecore

---

- **Sitecore Training**
- https://www.youtube.com/user/sitecoreceptraining

---

- **Friday Sitecore Best Practice**
- https://www.youtube.com/user/vasyafomichev

---

- **Thomas Eldblom's Channel - All things Habitat**
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWHYrLQQIx9vaXcqF5UV9Wg

---

- **Dylan Young's Channel - Hands on Sitecore training**
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5krmrALirwZibfW9-c2JXw

---

- **Short unofficial, ad-hoc, Sitecore SXA tutorials**
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn_P819AlbNv_maQCqrKp4g

---

- **Gopikrishna Gujjula's channel**
- https://www.youtube.com/c/GopiGujjula

---

- **Sitecore User Group channels**
- [Sitecore User Group Bangalore](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCn13gdm520Id_8o2rwyOkfQ)

---

### E-books

(note: Don't edit in copyright infringing links to e.g. John West's book here)

- **The Quick-Start Guide to Sitecore DMS success**
- http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/11-2-12-dmsebook
- **Sitecore XP: Valtech Insights**
- https://go.valtech.com/Sitecore-XP-Valtech-Insights.html

---

### Books / Recommended Reading

- **A List of Books That Every Sitecore Developer Should Read**
- A comprehensive listing by Mike Reynolds
- Twitter: [@mike_i_reynolds](https://twitter.com/mike_i_reynolds)
- Url: https://sitecorejunkie.com/2015/06/22/a-list-of-books-that-every-sitecore-developer-should-read/

---

- **Sitecore Developer Bookshelf 2018**
- A comprehensive listing by Peter Prochazka
- Twitter: [@chorpo](https://twitter.com/chorpo)
- Url: http://tothecore.sk/2018/07/23/sitecore-developer-bookshelf-2018

---

- **Professional Sitecore 8 Development: A Complete Guide to Solutions and Best Practices**
  This book is targeted towards both the beginning Sitecore developer with no experience as well as those seasoned Sitecore developers looking to improve the stability, maintainability and quality of their Sitecore solutions.
- [https://www.amazon.com/Professional-Sitecore-Development-Solutions-Practices/dp/1484222911](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484222911)

---

- **Practical Sitecore 8 Configuration and Strategy: A User Guide for Sitecore's Content and Marketing Capabilities**
  This book is targeted towards the marketer looking to get the most out of their investment in the Sitecore platform.
- [https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Sitecore-Configuration-Strategy-Capabilities/dp/1484212371](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484212371)

---

- **Sitecore Cookbook for Developers: Over 70 incredibly effective and practical recipes to get you up and running with Sitecore development**
  This book is targeted towards beginner Sitecore developers as well as experienced who want to explore core Sitecore architecture for site development, doing customizations, improving performance, and scalability.
- [https://www.amazon.com/Sitecore-Cookbook-Developers-Yogesh-Patel/dp/1784396524/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1784396524)

---

### Ask questions and Connect with Experts

Obviously, Sitecore Stack Exchange has great materials for getting answers to your questions. Here are some other ways to ask your questions:

- Community Forums: [community.sitecore.net](https://community.sitecore.net/)
- Slack chat: [sitecore.chat](https://sitecore.chat)
- Telegram: [t.me/SitecoreTelegram](https://t.me/SitecoreTelegram)

---

### Get Sandboxing

Above all, only reading or going through blog or articles won't do it all. Start with a Sitecore Sandbox application and for any of the Sitecore components or modules...integrate them - break them and fix them until you get it right. That has helped me always. I am big fan of Sandbox Apps.

Comment: Another good Sitecore 101 video from the Sitecore Virtual User Group: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLyOQ_wb9aM