# Data template for header and footer

Tags: templates

I am quite new to sitecore and want to know if there is a way where i will just create header and footer component once and reuse them in all my pages without having to select them on individual pages.
For e.g. i have a site with 100 pages and each page having same master layout containing header and footer. I can create a base page template with header and footer rendering assigned to it but i do not want to go to individual pages and select header and footer as datasource for the rendering.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information. What template or templates are your pages based on?  What technology (webforms or mvc)?  The more you can share the better, or the question risks getting shot down as too broad.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I am using MVC. I have good amount of experience in another .net based CMS SDL tridion and trying to correlate. In Tridion, I would have created a partial view page for header and footer and will include in the master layout. The partical view for header and footer will have their corresponding component. Is it possible\right approach to do the same in sitecore.

Comment: This is too broad. Answering this to match your level of Sitecore experience would not be appropriate for this format. I recommend joining us on Slack, and taking a look at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a template for the header and footer datasources. Create a datasource items somewhere in your content tree. Then you need to add a `__Standard Values` for your base page template. After that you should add the footer and header renderings at the presentation of the `__Standard Values` and select the corresponding datasource for those. You need do that once and the other pages will inherit that from base template.

Comment: I would like to add that the process of adding Standard Values is everything but intuitive, especially for new developers: you need to select the "Builder" section of your Template, then select "Builder Options" and finally click on "Standard Values".

You can see the details here:
https://www.screencast.com/t/3bbVZLk5zu

Comment: Thanks Artsem, Would it be a good idea to create separate pages for header and footer and then calling them in master layout?

Comment: If I understood you right, I don't think it is good idea. You shouldn't call any other pages in the master layout. It is not good approach in general. You jast need to add the base template and set for it the layout and renderings that are common for each page. After that you need to inherit your page's templates from it.

Comment: You can't add the header and footer in the layout without hard coding them in. And that is 100% against what Sitecore was built for.