# As a beginner , what version of Sitecore should I setup and practice 8 or 9?

Tags: installation

I have just started learning sitecore.

For a normal POC , which version of Sitecore should I use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say the answer to this is partly dependant on the future projects you might be working on. Do you have an 8.x project lined up or an upgrade to 9 coming up? or are you going to be starting on Sitecore 9?. If you don't have any projects coming up and you are just learning to widen your skills / get into Sitecore development then I'd say go for 9.

Comment: @Adam, good point but as both Chris and Pratik have noted , Sitecore 8 has easy installation hence for time being will go with Sitecore 8.2 and later will try Sitecore 9.

Comment: Yeah there is no doubt that 8.x is much quicker to install than 9 so it is a good starting point. Many clients are still on 8.x (or below) so it makes sense. There are some new features and functionality only available in 9 though and some differences to be aware of but is certainly a good idea to learn 8 and then the changes/differences in 9 if you have time to and you will be able to hit the ground running quicker on 8.x.

Comment: If you only want to use the core platform features to learn (i.e. no the xDB/Analytics parts) then you can install Sitecore 9 in CMS-only mode (XM) using SIM, which makes it much simpler to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Sitecore Development !

You can try Sitecore 8x if you want to practice at a very beginner level as it is easy to install.

Please make sure to use latest update i.e. Sitecore 8.2 update 7 from following link:

[Sitecore 8.2 Update 7](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update7.aspx)

Moreover , Sitecore has a very easy to understand documentation of setting up Sitecore and Visual Studio for development.

[Set up Sitecore and Visual Studio for development](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/set_up_sitecore_and_visual_studio_for_development)

Moreover , you can watch a demo video of Sitecore from CEP channel on youtube.

[Geeting Started Sitecore MVC - Getting Started](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3Mwcphtz4w)

Comment: Be careful not to blindly tick answers from co-workers and/or colleagues, when better answers are presented.

Comment: @Mark , yes sure, other answers are more descriptive but this was one of the earliest answer and had included video link as well.

Pratik is not my colleague or co-wotker by the way , lol , sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 6):

The hardest part of Sitecore 9 is the install. Sitecore 8 and [SIM tool](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Instance_Manager.aspx) is quick and easy. But the core of Sitecore's strength is in xConnect, which is in Sitecore 9.

I made a video of an easy way to get Sitecore 9 up. If you can do it, use 9. Else [SIM tool](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Instance_Manager.aspx) with 8.2 is a great place to start.

https://www.waitingimpatiently.com/install-sitecore-like-a-ci-nerd/

For learning Sitecore, this is a fantastic place to start. [How can I get started learning Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore)

Comment: To to add here - you should start learning on what ever version you are going to be implementing. While 8 is easier to install, if you are going to be implementing a v9 site. You don't really gain anything by installing quick. You should learn the install process too and learn on that version.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the Sitecore dev community!

I would recommend skipping Sitecore 8 and start already with Sitecore 9. Maybe the installation is a bit easier for Sitecore 8 with [Sitecore Instance Manager (SIM) tool](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager) but working with Sitecore 9 and xConnect especially is much more straight forward. You can also use [SIFless](https://bitbucket.org/RAhnemann/sif-less/overview) tool to install Sitecore 9 much easier.

With Sitecore 8 you also have to install Mongo DB to store analytics data and also RoboMongo or similar tool to query it. It brings more complexity during debugging and finding issues. You also have to learn Mongo query language which is completely different to TSQL used in MS SQL Server.

With Sitecore 9 you are doing selects to only SQL Server server and using therefore only TSQL commands.

Sitecore 9 has great new features like role based configuration, configuration layers and lots of built in functionality previously only available as modules like dynamic placeholders. Use can also install [Sitecore SXA](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator) to speed up initial development and content creation.

You can follow my blog post to help you out installing latest version of Sitecore 9 -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/06/22/sitecore-9-update-2-sitecore-9-0-2-installation/

Don't forget that you can now get 60 days Sitecore develop trial license. More information [here](https://www.sitecore.com/getting-started/developer-trial).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise going through the **Sitecore Developer Foundations** training which is free. While doing this course, you will create a sample Sitecore website using. You can get 60 days trial license from Sitecore. Once developer foundation training is done, go for Sitecore 9 certification.

https://elearning.sitecore.net/public/searchResults?q=&ty=ML.BASE.DV.SearchAnyWords

[image]