# How to build Sitecore Application with Visual Studio 2017 with MVC pattern OR HELIX methodology?

Tags: mvc, helix, visual-studio

As i am new to `sitecore` and though i have basic understanding on how to `create site` through `sitecore's content editor` and using `CMS`.

Now, i want to create a `web application/website using Visual Studio for Sitecore development`. Need to know from basic. `i.e` what are the `benefits` of using `MVC` to develop `sitecore application`? And same question goes with developing a site using `HELIX`. Plus, `how to build the application from scratch`.

Moreover, i have gone through the `doc.sitecore.com` which has `visual studio setup information but not suffice` on how to develop the `application from scratch`.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/set-up-sitecore-and-visual-studio-for-development.html

`Prerequisites` -

`1. I have Visual studio 2017
 2. Local sitecore instance 9.2`

I would like to know if anyone would `help me` in this by `suggesting` anything or any `link or application solution` which `developed` either in `MVC or using HELIX principles`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might want to check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore

Comment: you find this link about helix https://www.techguilds.com/blog/2018/07/back-to-basics-how-to-set-up-a-sitecore-helix-solution-from-scratch