# How to download Sitecore source code to set locally in visual studio

Tags: training-certification

I know this question is not regarding coding, but I did not found any solution so I am posting this question here.

I want to setup sitecore locally in my visual studio, but when I try to download it from there dev center they are telling this download is available only for certified developer.

1. So now how can I get source code to make working in my local system ?
2. Why they are not making available for all developer who want to learn it.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a Sitecore Trial license; I used it back in 2018. But checking the website now looks like it has been replaced with Front-End License, not sure if that will give you access to the complete platform or only the JSS part, but it worth trying out.

https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/developer-trial