# Is it possible to get access to training materials for Sitecore® Experience Solution 9 Developer Certification?

Tags: training-certification

I want to prepare for the `Sitecore® Experience Solution 9 Developer Certification`. However, I can't find anywhere some training courses, notes, or any material which will help with the preparation.

I did find some links but they were returning 404. Thus, do you guys know if there are any materials available for such preparation or it's not at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Sitecore Stack Exchange. You should start by looking at the sitecore training options listed on the documentation page https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/training and also at the official courses available on https://learning.sitecore.com/. After you enlist to the certification you'll also get some training questions and topics that will be covered during the exam.

In order to pass the sitecore certification make sure you are proficient in covering all areas of the exam competencies which are described https://learning.sitecore.com/exam/sitecore-experience-solution-9-developer-certification-1. For this you would need to either cover them through the online training courses or by having experience working as a Sitecore developer as listed in the prerequisites for the exam.

If you are planning on learning sitecore and becoming a developer please take a look at the post [How can I get started learning Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore) and https://www.sitecore.com/knowledge-center/getting-started/developing-on-sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

If someone from your organization is Sitecore Certified or your organization is a Sitecore partner then you can log in to https://learning.sitecore.com/ and access the training course there.

If not I think you can email `training@sitecore.net` and they may give you an answer to this.

Comment: Now I understand why I can't access those courses... Yeah, the company I work form is a Sitecore partner
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are already working on a real Sitecore project then you have a good amount of knowledge to pass the certification exam because most of the questions are scenario-based and require you to think through a problem instead of reciting something from memory. However, if you have just started learning Sitecore and want to appear for certification without prior working experience on the Sitecore project then also need not worry, there are plenty of resource out there, which should be helpful to thoroughly prepare you for the exam.

**Sitecore eLearning Platform:** On the Sitecore e-learning platform ([learning.sitecore.com](https://learning.sitecore.com/)), you can enrol yourself in the [Sitecore Experience Platform—Technical Product Solution](https://learning.sitecore.com/pathway/sitecore-experience-platform--technical) which consists of the following Collections: Developer’s Fundamentals, Sitecore Experience Accelerator, Helix, Java Script Services, and System Administrator. These collections teach you many of the fundamentals of Sitecore, the platform, Sitecore terminology, patterns, and implementations.

**Instructor-led online training**: On e-learning platform, you can register for this course [Sitecore Experience Solution Developer 9.1](https://learning.sitecore.com/instructor-led-training/sitecore-experience-solution-developer-91). The course focuses on MVC design patterns, Sitecore’s Presentation Architecture, the creation of dynamic presentations, the utilization of the Sitecore API, interactions with visitors to your site, the implementation of search-driven capabilities, the use of Sitecore Security Architecture, and Sitecore workflows. The purchase of a seat in the Sitecore Experience Solution Developer 9.1 course includes the option to take the Sitecore Developer certification exam.

**Additional resources**: Have a look at [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore) thread which will provide you with a list of resources to start with Sitecore learning.

Comment: Yes, I've working with Sitecore for about 2 years. I saw those courses from Sitecore which I could enroll but they're all paid and 3000$ is not cheap at all

Comment: If your organization is a partner with Sitecore, then you can enrol for these courses for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you enroll this course: **[Sitecore® Experience Solution 9 Developer Certification – Certification](https://learning.sitecore.com/exam/sitecore-experience-solution-9-developer-certification-1)**

You can have some material as well as the instruction to take this exam, these are example questions which are like the same question on Online Proctored

They contains also the coupon which you can register the exam online in this link https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=login&branding=SITECORE. That coupon was be cost $300

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple courses are available on [learning.sitecore.com](https://learning.sitecore.com/) which you can do.

You can do training on `Developer's Fundamentals 9.3 Collection` it will give you Sitecore 9.3 knowledge.

[image]

Also, there are some sample questions which you can find [here](https://www.swatiguptablogs.com/2019/06/sitecore-certification-sample-questions.html)