# I am new to Sitecore, What is the best training and learning material

Tags: sitecore-client

My enterprise company planning to adopt and implement Sitecore, I am totally new to Sitecore.
I don't know the starting point to learn & what are best learning materials as I search Sitecore eLearning and found expensive courses there.

please guide me

thnx

Comment: Join the MVP mentorship program https://mvp.sitecore.com/Mentor-Program, and engage with the community Slack network https://sitecore.chat/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **Sitecore Stack Exchange**,

The best point to start learning is [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1737/how-can-i-get-started-learning-sitecore/1738#1738).

There is a lot of interesting and helpful information about:

1. Blogs
2. Youtube channels
3. E-Books
4. Online trainings

I am sure that there you can find something that is appropriate for you.